# Can I get backlinks for a given url using Google APIs (Python)

Tags: python, google-api, google-search-console

As the title states I'm looking for a way to get backlinks for a given url / website using Google APIs, since I already have an api key and I'd rather use it instead of relying on other services.

I already tested services like ahrefs, majestic, moz, serpstat etc and actually they can give me the infomation I need, but I was wondering if there was a way to do it with Google.

For what I've read during my past researches I saw that Google offered a way to do it, but then it became deprecated, so no more usable. Do they really took away this feature for good?

I've also noticed that Google offers a similar service with his Google Search Console, but it can just be used for your own website, I'd like to get those kind of information for a random given url.

Actually I will be using Python in my project, but I don't think there's a package able to deliver me these kind of data, or at least I looked for it and didn't find anything.
Any help would be appreciated.